# notifyDataSetChanged() blocks UI

Tags: android, listview, baseadapter

After I've downloaded a list of objects from a rest service, obviously in an AsyncTask, I set them into a custom BaseAdapter. When I call again the service to load more data and add them to the List of object, and call the notifyDataSetChanged() the ListView block for a sec or two.

I've tried to move the add and notify into another AsyncTask but since I'm modifying the UI this raised an exception.

I've tried also to change the addAll with a loop where I add an item at time and call the notifyDataSetChanged() everytime but with no success.

Which is the best practice in this case?

Sorry for no code but I'm from my phone, this thing really puzzles me.

Comment: what are you trying to load and how many are you trying to load? Calling notifyDatasetChanged while you are looking is not going to do anything but make it worse because it is repopulating the entire list every time

Comment: Hmmm. I think you already did everything quite right... Maybe the whole layouting takes that much time? Do you recycle your views? If not, try if that helps.

Comment: `notifyDataSetChanged()` itself does not block AFAIK. What happens is that it tells `ListView` to redraw. But that should not block for 2 seconds and then run smoothly either. I guess you are doing some of sort of heave data processing or loading within the UI thread. You can try to use the DDMS method profiler to see what blocks your main thread. Or post some code here

Answer (score 0):

How many times you are call notifyDataSetChanged()? You need to call it once, after you add all data. If you show code of your AsyncTask class and how do you use it, I will tell more.